# jQuery Mobile cached page and HTML base href

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, relative-path

My multi-page jQuery Mobile app spans a couple directories. One stateful page is cached with `data-dom-cache="true"`. When I navigate to it, the base path used for relative links (`$('base')[0].href`) isn't restored to the proper subdirectory; it's one level up. Seems like a jQuery Mobile bug.

To work around, I tried `$('base')[0].href = 'subdir';`. But executing that sends it down a rabbit hole of `subdir`s. Inside the page it gives me `subdir/subdir`, and from the Chrome console it's `subdir/subdir/subdir`.

Is this a quirk of Chrome or jQuery Mobile, and what else can I do to work around? It's not easy for me to test with another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Woops, I forgot to answer this back then. I believe the solution was to add another `<base>`, rather than modifying the existing tag, to avoid any quirks with relative URLs.